# Potentially bad audit for low-quality posts

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts, review-audits

So I just encountered this audit:
[image: audit]

I passed, but is this really a good test?  Yes, the answer was upvoted, but this is not a good answer by any means.  I *OKed* it since it was obviously deemed as helpful, but... Why was this used as a test case?

Comment: **+1** There's a canned delete reason for that sort of answer; *why* is this a known-good audit??

Comment: @michaelb958 I have no idea.  When I saw that it was an audit, I assumed that I failed...

Comment: Looks like pity upvoting. And without any flags. So the system has no way to know it's not a good answer. (audits are picked automatically/randomly it's not a manual process)

Comment: [The post in question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17880263/254830) - I've just flagged it for moderator attention.